# $l_1$ space not being inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Hello so I am just reading some book in functional analysis but there is some calculations that I am getting different results for, so in the book he tries to prove that indeed $l_1$ is normed space but not inner product space I agree with everything he said now when he proves that it is not a inner product space by not satisfying the parallelogram equality there something that I don't completely agree with.

Consider the following counter example: 
$(x_n) = \frac{1}{2^{n - 1}}$ and $(y_n) = \frac{2}{3^{n - 1}}$

I agree that $||(x_n)||_1 = 2$ and $||(y_n)|| = 3$ that comes directly from geometric series,but now what I don't understand he claims that
$||x_n - y_n||_1 = \frac{4}{3}$ and $||x_n + y_n||_1 = 5$

I don't agree with that however so let us do the calculation now to see why I don't agree :

By doing the series we get $||x_n - y_n||_1 = 5$ and $||x_n + y_n|| = 13$ I mean it doesn't also satisfies the parallelogram identity but was I the one who did the mistake or the book ?

Edit:
Thanks to two Daniel's I am indeed the one who is incorrect here is the reason.

For n = 3 we have $\frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{9} > 0 \rightarrow \frac{1}{4} > \frac{2}{9}$ So for n $\geq 3$ we have $(\frac{1}{4})^n > (\frac{2}{9})^n$

So for $(x_n) > (y_n)$ for case of n = 3, and it can be shown that 
(y_n) > (x_n) for n = 1,2.

So $||x_n - y_n||_1 = \Sigma_{n = 1}^{n = \infty}(|\frac{1}{2^{n - 1}} - \frac{2}{3^{n - 1}}|) = \Sigma_{n = 1}^{n = 2}(y_n - x_n) + \Sigma_{n = 3}^{n = \infty}(x_n - y_n) = \Sigma_{n = 1}^{n = 2}(y_n - x_n) + (\Sigma_{n = 0}^{n = \infty}(x_n - y_n) - \Sigma_{n = 0}^{n = 2}(x_n - y_n)) = (1 + \frac{1}{6}) + (-1 - [-1 + -\frac{1}{6}]) = \frac{4}{3}$

where I did the missing steps by resorting to geometric series formula.

Comment: I agree with the book. I just did the calculations. Your calculations seem wrong.

Comment: Since all numbers are positive, we have $\lVert x + y\rVert_1 = \lVert x\rVert_1 + \lVert y \rVert_1 = 2+3 =  5$. For $x - y$, you have to take into account that $x_n > y_n$ for $n \geqslant 3$, but $x_k < y_k$ for $k\leqslant 2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer the way I did it I just did it as normal computations and got the following formula $(\frac{1}{2})^{n -1} - 6*(\frac{2}{6})^n = 2*(\frac{1}{2})^n  - 6*((\frac{1}{3})^n)$ or plus from which I got 5 and 13 after taking absolute value.

Comment: Please, read carefully Daniel Fischer's comment and try again. Also, your evaluation of the geometric sums is wrong, they give $2$ and $3$ respectively.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%7C1%2F2%5E%28n+-+1%29+-+2%2F3%5E%28n+-+1%29%7C+from+n%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I see where I am wrong now I understand daniel Fisher's computation for $||x + y||_1$ but trying how to do x - y computation 1 moment.

Comment: okay I am back I agree with @DanielFischer answer just few seconds I will modify the question in case anybody needs it for later.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I have done it also edited my question above to show my calculation thank you and Daniel fisher's for your help..

Comment: Great! Good continuation :)